# Inner Join 2 Column Return

Tags: self-join, join

I need to build a query that I believe needs different types of joins, but I am not sure how to write it.

I have a customers table and an orders table. I need a query that will return 2 columns displaying the following:

1- list of all customer_id that have never had an order

2- list of all customer_ID that have 1 or more record in the orders table

I have this left join query but i feel like its missing something that indicates the customers column should not have a value on the orders table?

```
SELECT Customers.userid, Orders.userid
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN ORDERS
ON Customers.userid=orders.USER_ID
```

Comment: This will give you ALL records from the Customers table and only records from the ORDERS table having orders. You will see NULL values in place of order information where a customer has never ordered.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli thank you, that is want I want. 2 Questions

1- is there a way to remove the Null values for customers who have no orders?

2- if i group by user_ID would this help?

Comment: 1 - No, not really.  You are pulling all the data into a single dataset; the lack of data is represented by a NULL value.  You could use an `INNER JOIN` but then you'd lose the customers that have never ordered.  2 - no.  Group by is an aggregation statement.  It might help if you listed the two tables columns and a representation of what kind of output you want to see.

Comment: Would there be a way to use IFNULL to remove records from the right able orders?

Comment: Just use an 'INNER JOIN' if you want them gone.  But again, you will be missing all of the customers that have never ordered.  You could use the IFNULL if you want to change the NULL value to something else like `Never Ordered`.  But you would need to change the datatype, most likely of the Orders.UserID in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Please give example input and desired output to clarify what you want.